# изменить цвет раскрывающимся спискам jquery

Tags: jquery

Как данному скрипту добавить изменение цвета фона активного блока

```
 var $texts = $('.view-source .hide');
        $texts.not(':first').hide();
        $('.view-source .class_click').on('click', function () {
            $texts.slideUp(500);

            $(this).parent().find('.hide').slideDown(500);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вашу проблему, то вам надо использовать [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

`your_element.css("background-color", your_colour);`

Comment: так работает, но при выборе нового меню старое продолжает светиться

Comment: @LLIAKAJI очевидно, что старое надо возвращать в исходный цвет который вам надо. Можно этим же способом.